# Stripe CheckoutForm component displays nothing on React Router using <Link>

Tags: reactjs, react-router, stripe-payments

When I `<Link>` to a Stripe's `CheckoutForm` component, nothing displays. I'm following the Stripe with React instructions here https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/elements-react#setup but it does not include steps for integrating with React Router.

It is functional if I use the component as `<CheckoutForm />` but not as `<Link to='/checkoutForm' />` with router.

I've tried wrapping the Router in app.js with `<stripeProvider>` and `<Elements>` but then it not only displays nothing, but messes up the other routes.

I've also tried rendering a container component in place of `<CheckoutForm />` to avoid `<Link>` but same problem.

```
            <StripeProvider apiKey="pk_test_lKyP93clx4TYCo2CTdLxtMY3">
                <Elements>
                    <Link to='/checkoutForm' className='panel flex center' style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}><button className='bold grey'>Purchase Followers</button></Link>                
                </Elements>
            </StripeProvider>
```

Code below works but I don't want to render `<CheckoutForm />` I want to Link to it

```
            <StripeProvider apiKey="pk_test_lKyP93clx4TYCo2CTdLxtMY3">
                <Elements>
                    <CheckoutForm />                  
                </Elements>
            </StripeProvider>
```

I've tried below:

```
<StripeProvider apiKey="pk_test_lKyP93clx4TYCo2CTdLxtMY3">
            <Router>
                <Fragment>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                        <Elements >
                            <Route path="/checkoutForm" component={CheckoutForm} />
                        </Elements>
                        <Route path="/:id/edit" component={Edit} />
                        <Route path="/:id/delete" component={Delete} />
                        <Route path="/:id" component={ChirpContainer} />
                    </Switch>
                </Fragment>
            </Router>
        </StripeProvider>
```

**Edit:** In studying the Stripe instructions and this example https://codesandbox.io/s/l72l6k779q, these few things are clear:

- there is a container component for the Stripe elements
- wherever the container component is rendered, it is wrapped with `<StripeProvider>` and `<Elements>`
- the container component is exported with `injectStripe`

Now, my issue is that I don't render the container component in the usual way; I want to render it in a Link through the router. **So where and how do I wrap the container component with StripeProvider and Elements if it's in a Router Link?**

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you have your nesting backwards. I think `StripeProvider` and its elements should be within your `CheckoutForm` component. Something like:

```
<Router>
  <Link to='/checkout-form'>Check out</Link>

  <hr />

  <Route path='checkout-form' component={CheckoutForm} />  
</Router>
```

Then in `CheckoutForm` you'd have something like this in your render function:

```
<StripeProvider apiKey='pk_test_lKyP93clx4TYCo2CTdLxtMY3'>
  <Elements>
    // ...your Stripe elements and other form elements
  </Elements>
</StripeProvider>
```

In terms of children, it should be `Router` > `StripeProvider` > your form.

Comment: Tried that; still nothing. The Stripe instructions show wrapping <StripeProvider> and <Elements> in the file where <checkoutForm /> is rendered.

Comment: But I think I see what you're saying, I'll try something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/l72l6k779q